# Trouble on the behavior of a JavaScript function that `return this`

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.1.1 and in my `application.js` file I have the following code that enables page scrolling:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.scrollTo = function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top + 'px'
    }, 'fast');
    return this; // for chaining...
  }
})( jQuery );
```

I can use the above function in my `js` responses like so:

```
$('#target_id').scrollTo();

# other JS code...
```

It works most of the times, except in the following scenario: given I run the function in a `js` response when the `#target_id` is *not* found on the page from where the `js` request had been fired then the `other JS code...` does *not* run. My conclusion is that the `scrollTo()` function breaks something since all works if I remove it.

Why does it happen? What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if selector found some results. For example with `if (!$(this).length) return;` (or use other validation before accessing `.offset()` method).

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.scrollTo = function() {
    if (!$(this).length) return;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top + 'px'
    }, 'fast');
    return this; // for chaining...
  }
})( jQuery );
```

---

Or just wrap everything with `try{}catch(){}`

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.scrollTo = function() {
    try {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top + 'px'
        }, 'fast');
        return this; // for chaining...
    }
    catch(err) {}
  }
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works! I would like also to understand why I should validate `this` before accessing the `.offset()` method and what others validation should I run. It is hard to find, debug and check those kinds of errors in browsers...

Comment: I do not have much experience in JavaScript so could you show me how you'd solve the problem, maybe by using `try/catch`?

Comment: So, by using `try/catch`, when a error happens then the JavaScript code'd continue to run in any case?

Comment: In most cases it would. But don't use it too much. In this case it's good, but don't try to `try/catch` every line of your code. Try to know what you are coding and avoid errors. Use your browsers debugger (firebug in firefox, or other browsers "inspect element" feature) to see if you have any errors. In this case error occurs because you try to access non existing property/method of object. For example if you have some `obj = {a:1,b:2}` and try to access `obj.c()` which is undefined - you will get error. As I said, my advice is to check you browsers console If you have some errors. Good luck!